# Looping through and comparing subsets of arrays

Tags: c, algorithm

I have two arrays:

```
int group_id[] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3};
int value[]    = {1, 0, 3, 5, 0, 2, 1, 6};
```

From the second array, I need to return the largest value within the `group_id` index (not including the current index position), the result (in a new array) would be:

```
{0, 1, 5, 3, 5, 6, 6, 2}
```

The arrays are a lot longer (~10 millions), so looking for an efficient solution.

---

Clarification:
The first two elements of `value` belong to `group_id` = 1, the first element will return 0 as the highest value as it can't return its self. The second element will will return 1 as it's the largest value in `group_id` 1.

the third, fourth and fifth elements (3, 5, 0) belong to `group_id` 2, the first will return 5, the second 3 (as it can't return its own index and the third will return 5).

> It isn't clear that all the elements in group_id with the same number are adjacent (but that is crucial for efficiency).

Good point, you can assume they are all adjacent.

> It isn't clear what should happen if there was only one entry in group_id with a given value — there isn't an alternative entry to use, so what should happen (or should the code abandon ship if the input is invalid).

Assume invalid.

Comment: I've looked at the inputs, the output and the description, and I've no idea how you generate that output from the inputs, nor the significance of the "not including the current index position" comment.  Maybe you need to explain more clearly what you're trying to do.  Is it coincidental that the `group_id` array is in sorted order?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler and here I thought I was the only one.

Comment: Same here. Absolutely unclear what you are trying to do, also "efficient solution" is an unclear term, too. How should one avoid visiting every single item of your array? Is there any pattern to the data to make creation of the output more efficient (since your example output has the same length as the two inputs)?

Comment: Regardless, this seems far more an *algorithm* question than a question about C.

Comment: Maybe…start with index 0 in the output array (O). You scan the group array for the value in group[0] (aka 1) and find the maximum entry in values array with the same group number but not the one in index 0. The group[0] value is 1, so the other entry (group[1]) matches, and the value[1] is 0.  There are no other candidates, so O[0] = 0.  For O[1], the group[1] value is 1, and so the entry value[0] is the output — O[1] == 1.  For O[2], the group changes to 2, and the other entries are 5 and 0, so O[2] is 5; for O[3], the other elements are 3 and 0, so O[3] is 3; then O[4] is 5 again, etc.

Comment: It isn't clear that all the elements in `group_id` with the same number are adjacent (but that is crucial for efficiency).  It isn't clear what should happen if there was only one entry in `group_id` with a given value — there isn't an alternative entry to use, so what should happen (or should the code abandon ship if the input is invalid).  You probably only need to track the maximum and second maximum values in the values for a given group_id value — the output will be one or the other of those two values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved in O(N) time; it does not need O(N•log N) and sorting.  This code shows how:

```
/* SO 5723-6683 */
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void dump_array(const char *tag, int size, int *data);
static void test_array(const char *tag, int size, int *groups, int *values);

int main(void)
{
    int groups1[] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 };
    int values1[] = { 1, 0, 3, 5, 0, 2, 1, 6 };
    int groups2[] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
    int values2[] = { 1, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 1, 6, 6, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 3, 7, 3 };
    enum { NUM_VALUES1 = sizeof(values1) / sizeof(values1[0]) };
    enum { NUM_VALUES2 = sizeof(values2) / sizeof(values2[0]) };

    test_array("Test 1", NUM_VALUES1, groups1, values1);
    test_array("Test 2", NUM_VALUES2, groups2, values2);
    return 0;
}

static void test_array(const char *tag, int size, int *groups, int *values)
{
    printf("%s (%d):\n", tag, size);
    dump_array("values", size, values);
    dump_array("groups", size, groups);

    int output[size];
    int grp_size;
    for (int lo = 0; lo < size - 1; lo += grp_size)
    {
        assert(groups[lo+0] == groups[lo+1]);
        grp_size = 2;
        int max_1 = (values[lo+0] < values[lo+1]) ? values[lo+1] : values[lo+0];
        int max_2 = (values[lo+0] < values[lo+1]) ? values[lo+0] : values[lo+1];
        for (int hi = lo + 2; hi < size && groups[hi] == groups[lo]; hi++)
        {
            grp_size++;
            if (values[hi] >= max_1)
            {
                max_2 = max_1;
                max_1 = values[hi];
            }
            else if (values[hi] >= max_2)
                max_2 = values[hi];
        }
        for (int i = lo; i < lo + grp_size; i++)
            output[i] = (values[i] == max_1) ? max_2 : max_1;
    }

    dump_array("output", size, output);
}

static void dump_array(const char *tag, int size, int *data)
{
    printf("%s (%d):", tag, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf(" %d", data[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Output from this test program:

```
Test 1 (8):
values (8): 1 0 3 5 0 2 1 6
groups (8): 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
output (8): 0 1 5 3 5 6 6 2
Test 2 (18):
values (18): 1 1 3 5 0 2 1 6 6 3 5 5 5 3 2 3 7 3
groups (18): 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5
output (18): 1 1 5 3 5 6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 7 7 7 3 7
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will do it. Its efficiency is *O*(sum of all *n*_*i*log(*n*_*i*)) in which *n*_*i* is the size of each subset *i*, unless we use MPI or OpenMP (in that case, it will be at best *O*(*m*log(*m*)), in which *m* is the size of the greatest subset).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int compare (const void * e1, const void * e2) 
{
    int f = *((int*)e1);
    int s = *((int*)e2);
    return (f>s);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int group_id[] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3};
    int value[]    = {1, 0, 3, 5, 0, 2, 1, 6};

    int i,j,k,count,*tmp;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        /* find subsets */
        count = 1;
        for (j=i; j<7 && group_id[j]==group_id[j+1]; j++)
            count++;
        /* copy subset */
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(int)*count);
        memcpy(tmp, &value[i], sizeof(int)*count);
        /* sort */
        qsort (tmp, count, sizeof(*tmp), compare);
        /* print */
        for (k=i; k<=j; k++)
            if (value[k] != tmp[count-1])
                printf("%d ", tmp[count-1]);
            else
                printf("%d ", tmp[count-2]);
        i = j;
        free(tmp);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

PS: You will probably have to do some modifications to it, but I hope its enough for what you want (or to get you started). Please, be aware, I am assuming each subset has size at least 2, and that the greatest value within a subset appears only once.

Comment: You could also arrange data in pair sets (group_id, value) and sort them all, which could be more efficient than the above method, but I am not sure whether you can do it. If it is a stream of data or the data is too big for the available RAM, the above approach probably is one of the best.